# Congruences that aren't "finite from above," take 2: semigroups

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, order-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, universal-algebra

This is a hopefully less trivial version of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459576/congruences-that-arent-finite-from-above). Briefly, say that a congruence is **parafinite** if it is the largest congruence contained in some equivalence relation with finitely many classes; see the linked question for the more detailed definition.

I'm interested in "nontrivial" examples of non-parafinite congruences. I still don't have a great sense of what the right notion of nontriviality is here, but hopefully the following will produce interesting cases:

> Is there an example of a countably infinite semigroup with a non-parafinite congruence?

The cardinality restriction here is to hopefully rule out unilluminating set-theoretic constructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is also trivial.  Sorry, just take a semigroup with the identity xy=x. Then all equivalence relations are congruences so this is the same as pure sets.

Here is a more interesting construction which might count as less trivial.  Let $S$ be any semigroup and fix an element $s\in S$.  Let $X$ be any infinite set.  Make $S\cup X$ into a semigroup by putting $xt=st$, $tx=ts$ for any $x,\in X$ and $t\in S$.   Then given any equivalence relation on $X$, we can get a congruence on $S\cup X$ by putting elements of $S$ into singleton classes and doing this equivalence relation on $X$.  In your equivalence relation on $X$ has infinitely many classes, then the resulting congruence should not be parafinite (but I would need to write the details).

Comment: Do you know what a better version of this question might be?

Comment: I think you can basically build nonparafinite congruences whenever you have an algebra $A$ with an infinite subset $X$ such that any equivalence relation on $X$ extends to a congruence on $A$ with each element of $A$ in singleton congruence classes.

Comment: I meant with each element of A/X in singleton classes.