# Can the set of parafinite congruences be descriptive-set-theoretically complicated?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, descriptive-set-theory, order-theory, universal-algebra

Fix an algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ with underlying set $\mathbb{N}$ and finite language $\Sigma$. The set of congruences on $\mathfrak{A}$ is a closed subset $C_\mathfrak{A}$ of $2^\mathbb{N}$ (with the usual topology).

Given an equivalence relation $E\subseteq\mathbb{N}^2$, let $\sim_E$ be the largest congruence of $\mathfrak{A}$ contained in $E$. Say that a congruence $\sim$ is **parafinite** iff $\sim=\sim_E$ for some $E$ with finitely many classes. Prima facie, the set $P_\mathfrak{A}$ of parafinite congruences is quite complicated, namely $\Sigma^1_1$: the key point (bringing this down from $\Sigma^1_2$) is that $\sim=\sim_E$ iff for every $(a,b)\in E\setminus\sim$ there is a "proof" in an appropriate sense that identifying $a$ and $b$ in an $\mathfrak{A}$-congruence would force an identification of $E$-distinct elements.

I'm curious whether this bound can be improved. To start with an ambitious question:

> Can $P_\mathfrak{A}$ be non-Borel?

Even a much weaker result, though, would be interesting to me:

> Can $P_\mathfrak{A}$ be non-$\Sigma^0_2$?

The point here is that $\Sigma^0_2$ is the complexity of telling whether an equivalence relation has finitely many classes. So at the very least, doing better(/worse?) than $\Sigma^0_2$ would be an indicator of some genuine complexity of this notion.

*This was actually the original question I was interested in, motivating my earlier questions on parafiniteness. I'd originally thought that this one was intractable, but given that my [earlier](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459576/congruences-that-arent-finite-from-above) [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459580/congruences-that-arent-finite-from-above-take-2-semigroups) turned out trivial I'm going ahead and asking this one.*